# IAPs are being restoring when they have not yet been purchased yet

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

When the user calls restorePurchases(), the non-consumable com.premium is restored even thought they do not own it.
Here are the functions that are responsible for the restoring purchases and purchasing IAPs. This is only an issue with non-consumable IAPs.
There is no issue with purchasing. And if the user attempts to purchase an IAP that they already have, it is simply restored. Thank you for looking in to this.

```
func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")

    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction 

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
        print("starting restoring")
        switch prodID {
        case "com.premium":
            print("restoring ads")
            removeAds()
        case "com.cash":
            print("we dont restore coins")
        case "com.level":
            print("we dont restore levels")
        default:
            print("can't restore")
        }
    }
```

Here is my payment queue also.

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .purchased:
            print("buying, ok unlock iap here")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "com.premium":
                print("buying ads")
                removeAds()
            case "com.cash":
                print("buying coins")
                addCoins()
            case "com.level":
                print("buying levels")
                addLevels()
            default:
                print("can't buy")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            print("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing with a brand new test user account each time?

Comment: @brandonscript Yes I have used a new account each time.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit, since it removed the original code that was the "problem" and to a degree invalidated the answer.  You can edit your question to include your "new" code as an addition if you like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not update any purchase status in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`. This function just lets you know that the restoration process has completed. You could use this to update your UI or display an alert or something.

The restoration process delivers the transactions to be restored to the `updatedTransactions` function where you handle the `.restored` state in the same way that you handle the `.purchased` state.

Essentially "restore" just replays the purchase transaction process for non-consumable and auto-renewing subscription purchase types.

Comment: So inside of my paymentQueue function, In the switch trans.transactionState. I should use the .restored case?

Comment: So when I call restorePurchases() it gets to the to the .restoringAttempt but the print(p.productIdentifier) prints a blank line in the console and thus it goes to default and states: can't buy. However, if I press on the purchase button, and sign in but do not purchase. Then I attempt to restore it works. So what do I need to include in my restorePurchases()  to be prompted to sign in the first time? Thanks again.

Comment: I can't see where you are getting `p` from in your code. It should be set from `transaction.payment`

Comment: var p = SKProduct()

Comment: Yeah, no. That just assigns p as an empty product. After `let trans = transaction as! ...` you should have `let p = trans.payment` - you want the payment from the transaction you are processing

Comment: Cannon assign value of type 'SKPayment' to type 'SKProduct'. Can't assign that to p. A few lines down, this happens too: let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String

Comment: you need to remove the definition of p as an SKProduct. You need it to be the SKPayment from the transaction and then you get the productIdentifier from the payment

Comment: I apologise, the error was based around the fact that I has another switch statement in the .restore case. So I removed that, as it wasn't getting told which product ID it could restore. So that was my bad. Thanks for the help with the original error though! You're a life saver!